# An integral and $\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, pi

I want to give you this question as an enigma.

Can you prove that the following integral is equal to $\pi$ ?

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{256x^4}{x^{12}+6x^{10}+15x^8+35x^4+6x^2+1}}=\pi.$$

---

This can be proven without the use of complex numbers.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266181/a-nasty-integral-of-a-rational-function

Comment: Thanks, but i want to see if someone can find the solution without the use of complex numbers.

Comment: [***Hahahahaha***...](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1822246/187051)

Comment: Are you sure it equals $\pi$?

Comment: I agree with @mickep. Mathematica gave me $3.085050028\cdots$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an attempt to pose a challenge that the poster already knows (or claims to know) the answer to; thus **Not A Real Question**.

Comment: I don't find this very stimulating, probably there is only a lot of calculations to do (the root will in some way simplified and bla bla bla you express it as the sum of some arctangents and then you have $\pi$) even a lot more if you don't want (why?) to use complex numbers. This is the kind of work that I let the computer do for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the denominator is supposed to be $$x^{12} + 6x^{10} + 15x^8 + 20x^6 + 15x^4 + 6x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + 1)^6$$ and the coefficient $20$ was somehow added to the wrong place. In that case, your integral is just $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{16x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ which is easy to solve by substituting $x = \tan(\theta)$: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{16 \tan(\theta)^2 \sec(\theta)^2}{\sec(\theta)^6} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 16 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\theta)^2 \cos(\theta)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \pi.$$ As mentioned in the comments, the given integral is incorrect.